# MCP2515 & STM32L053: SPI issue

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, spi, hal

I'm trying to make a MPC2515 CAN controller works with an STML053R8 µC.
I'm using this driver/example https://github.com/eziya/STM32_SPI_MCP2515 with just the `#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"` changed to `#include "stm32l0xx_hal.h"`.

Here is my condensed code:

```
#define CAN_CS_Pin GPIO_PIN_5
#define CAN_CS_GPIO_Port GPIOA

extern SPI_HandleTypeDef        hspi1;
#define SPI_CAN                 &hspi1

int CANSPI_Initialize(void)
{
  // Some registers def
  [...]

  // This pass
  if(MCP2515_Initialize() != 0)
    return 1;

  // This fails
  if(MCP2515_SetConfigMode() != 0)
    return 2;

  [...]
}

int MCP2515_Initialize(void)
{
  MCP2515_CS_HIGH();    

  uint8_t loop = 10;

  do {
    /* SPI Ready ? */
    if(HAL_SPI_GetState(SPI_CAN) == HAL_SPI_STATE_READY)
      return 0;

    loop--;
  } while(loop > 0);

  return 1;
}

int MCP2515_SetConfigMode(void)
{
  /* CANCTRL Register Configuration ?? ?? */  
  MCP2515_WriteByte(MCP2515_CANCTRL, 0x80);

  uint8_t loop = 10;

  do {      
    if((MCP2515_ReadByte(MCP2515_CANSTAT) & 0xE0) == 0x80)
      return 0;

    loop--;
  } while(loop > 0);

  return 1;
}

uint8_t MCP2515_ReadByte (uint8_t address)
{
  uint8_t retVal;

  MCP2515_CS_LOW();

  SPI_Tx(MCP2515_READ);
  SPI_Tx(address);
  retVal = SPI_Rx();

  MCP2515_CS_HIGH();

  return retVal;
}

void MCP2515_WriteByte(uint8_t address, uint8_t data)
{    
  MCP2515_CS_LOW();  

  SPI_Tx(MCP2515_WRITE);
  SPI_Tx(address);
  SPI_Tx(data);  

  MCP2515_CS_HIGH();
}
```

My SPI configuration (generated by STM32 CubeMX):

```
/* SPI1 init function */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}
```

and a link to the MPC2515 datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001801H.pdf

My problem here is in `MCP2515_SetConfigMode()`, as I set the `CANCTRL` register, I should read back
this value ('current mode is config mode') in `CANSTAT` register.

Also I tried to do the same thing for a LSM6DS3 IMU module yesterday and I got the same issue, unable
to read/write registers => unable to communicate with the device. I plugged it in I2C (this IMU got
2 interfaces) and I make it works like a charm.

The driver/example code I use seems very valid to me, I checked ALL the data & registers value from
the datasheet and everything looks OK to me. I suspect I might messed up something in my SPI configuration.

Any help will be gladly appreciated!

EDIT: I don't have a logical analyzer but I downloaded ones for Arduino and got this weird output. Not sure if this is the Arduino fault or my actual output:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is code related...

Comment: `MCP2515_Initialize(void)` does not do any communication with the MCP2515, hence from it succeeding you cannot infer that communication with the device works at all. Double check your pinout and connections, make sure the CS pin is initialized correctly (output!), then maybe hook up a logic analyzer to see if the data gets sent out from the STM32 right.

Comment: It may be a problem in your code, but you don't show enough code to tell. Over at ee-stackexchange you will find more people with experience in micro- and CAN-controllers.

Comment: Pinout and connections triple checked. CS pin initialized with CubeMX, getting "GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;". I don't have a logic analyzer currently but I edited my main message with an output made with an arduino.

Comment: The image shows a problem with both SCK and CS.

Comment: Yep. Let's take SCK for example, I don't have any specifics things to do with that. I use the HAL to init the SPI bus with all standards pins given by CubeMX (see code in my post) and I should have, as an output, a correct SCK. The generated code should be good (it is for I2C for example) and widely used by people so.. ?

Comment: Or let's take CS for example. It is managed by software but just wiggles around. Like SCK it looks as though the pin may be floating.

Comment: I tried several pins as CS and the 2 SPI available, nothing new...

Comment: Hey Jimmy, turns out you were right. I tried CS on PA2, PA3, etc. no success. Randomly (and desesperated) I tried on PC1... and it works.... !
I DO NOT understand why this is now working, there is nothing in the doc preventing me for using PA pins as GPIO output for CS...